# What is the learning path for the role of NLP engineer a beginner should follow?

Tags: nlp, beginner, career

I am data science enthusiast and have interest in NLP. How should I develop my understanding for the domain and prepare for the role of an NLP engineer? What are the must have skills to master NLP? Suggest few good reading resources/online courses

Comment: IMO this is open-ended question.

Comment: May be if you can provide any answer to sub-questions in description please